# Factory Method - Can / should a Factory have several methods that create the same class?

Tags: php, oop, factory, factory-pattern

Let's say I want to build a House and I have a house factory. The factory can already build houses using a blueprint. However, a new client comes in and asks us if we can build them a house from a sketch they provide. Would it be correct to add a new assembly line to the factory to handle these new houses? Or would it be preferable to create an entirely new factory for the homes built from a sketch? The output will always be a House, with specific attributes (i.e num sides, color, roof)

```
class House_Factory {
  public function create(Blueprint $blueprint) {
    $house = new House();
    $house->num_sides = $blueprint->num_sides;
    $house->color = $blueprint->color;
    $house->roof = $blueprint->roof;
    return $house;
  }

  // Is having another create method acceptable in a Factory?
  public function createFromSketch(Sketch $sketch) {
    $house = new House();
    $house->num_sides = $sketch->num_exterior_walls;
    $house->color = $sketch->exterior_wall_color;
    $house->roof = $sketch->roof;
    return $house;
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem right to me but I can't put my finger on it. Is there a better design pattern to follow for a situation like this?

Comment: You don't need a Factory class if you're always returning instances of the same `House` class. These can simply be methods in the `House` class.

Comment: They can also be a function. No need to put static methods in a class.

Comment: But otherwise, if the HouseFactory makes houses, it makes total sense to me to have multiple methods that take different arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *my opinion*, it would be acceptable to have both methods in the same class. Where it makes sense to break out into different classes (and implement an interface) is when you are creating different outputs with the same type of inputs - for instance if you needed to make `Houses`, `Churches`, and `Sheds`, they would each have a factory inheriting a `Building` interface, each with a `create` method that takes a `Blueprint` as an argument (where `Blueprint` may be an interface and each concrete factory requires it's own variation of `Blueprint`, etc...).

What makes your approach feel a little funny to me is that you have to name the `create` methods differently. In a strongly typed language like Java you would have multiple `create` methods, differentiated by the argument type, which is nice and clean.

Another approach you could consider, if appropriate, is translate your `Sketches` to `Blueprints` with some kind of adapter.

```
<?php

class Blueprint
{
    public $num_sides;
    public $color;
    public $roof;

    public function __construct($num_sides, $color, $roof)
    {
        $this->num_sides = $num_sides;
        $this->color     = $color;
        $this->roof      = $roof;
    }


}

class Sketch
{
    public $num_exterior_walls;
    public $exterior_wall_color;
    public $roof;

    public function __construct($num_exterior_walls, $exterior_wall_color, $roof)
    {
        $this->num_exterior_walls  = $num_exterior_walls;
        $this->exterior_wall_color = $exterior_wall_color;
        $this->roof                = $roof;
    }
}

class House
{
    public $num_sides;
    public $color;
    public $roof;

    public function toString()
    {
        return json_encode([
            'Sides' => $this->num_sides,
            'Color' => $this->color,
            'Roof' => $this->roof
        ]);
    }
}

class HouseFactory
{
    public function create(Blueprint $blueprint)
    {
        $house            = new House();
        $house->num_sides = $blueprint->num_sides;
        $house->color     = $blueprint->color;
        $house->roof      = $blueprint->roof;
        return $house;
    }
}

class BlueprintMapper
{
    public static function fromSketch(Sketch $sketch)
    {
        return new Blueprint($sketch->num_exterior_walls, $sketch->exterior_wall_color, $sketch->roof);
    }
}

$houseFactory = new HouseFactory();
$blueprint    = new Blueprint(4, 'Red', 'Slate');
$house1       = $houseFactory->create($blueprint);

$sketch          = new Sketch(4, 'Blue', 'Tin');
$sketchBlueprint = BlueprintMapper::fromSketch($sketch);
$house2          = $houseFactory->create($sketchBlueprint);

echo $house1->toString() . PHP_EOL;
echo $house2->toString() . PHP_EOL;

{"Sides":4,"Color":"Red","Roof":"Slate"}
{"Sides":4,"Color":"Blue","Roof":"Tin"}
```